# Unusual review appeared on First Post Queue

Tags: support, status-bydesign, review-queue

I was just doing some Reviews on the Fist Posts queue, and encountered [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103706/verbal-threat-needing-further-action):

[image]

This I found really unusual, as this is a **one month old answer**, which is even accepted and has more than 10 upvotes. It is also closed.

I checked the First Posts [history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) and of what I can see I was the only one to review it recently. Furthermore, exploring that history of reviews I can see that on the date of posting (12/7/17) user @scaaahu successfully reviewed it.

**Any reasons why this post came again on the review queue? Could this be some malfunction or bug, or has someone experienced this before?**

Comment: I think that we need a new status-UndocumentedFeature.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings did you find it unusual also? Seems to.be some sort of backsafe for reviews, but never have I noticed.

Comment: Its one of those bugs that has no real negative impact on the system, and is way too much work to fix.    So instead we call it an undocumented feature :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, the position of "first post" is dynamic.

[This related post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235034/162102) says:

> Questions are added to the queue when they qualify for it. Normally, a question qualifies as a "first post" when it is posted - but there are situations where this doesn't happen until later on:
>
> - ...
> - Other, earlier posts from the same author are deleted

That's what happened here.  This user had two posts, both answers.  The other one was on a [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96863/325) that was deleted today, taking its answers with it.  That answer was [previously reviewed as a first post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/61440) (by you, in fact), but it seems that information doesn't get recorded with the user.  Three minutes after the older question was deleted, the now-only post from this user [entered review](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/66663).

I agree it's peculiar.  I suppose erring on the side of more review is better, particularly if a new user posts a bunch of stuff at once.  There might be better ways to implement reviews, at the cost of code complexity and developer time, but I don't know if it's worth it.

Comment: Yep, seems that you are correct...Funny enough, this also explained to me why I lost 10 rep today, as I also had an answer on that deleted question. I also agree that we should err on the sire of more reviews, so seems that this behavior is useful.